# Error after upgrade from rails 3.1 to 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm

I set myself the task of upgrading my app from rails 3.1 to rails 3.2.6 on my local mac book air lion dev environment. I followed this [guide](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html) and ruby is upgraded, and all of my gems seemed to install and rails -v gives the answer of rails 3.2.6. If I run any rails commands though, e.g. rails c to start the console, I get this:

```
MacBook-Air:myapp bob$ rails c
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/pubnub-ruby-0.0.9/lib/pubnub-ruby.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./pubnub.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/pubnub-ruby-0.0.9/lib/pubnub-ruby.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /Users/bob/work/myapp/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Yes I do use pubnub in my app - it's always been working fine so I don't suspect it necessarily is the problem.

The application.rb line 13 (might be not be relevant) is

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

I do precompile assets before deploying.

The /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails32/gems/pubnub-ruby-0.0.9/lib/pubnub-ruby.rb:1 file is present and I opened it fine.

Does anyone know whats going on / is it pubnub specific or something else? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further and googling hasn't brought anything up so far.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the file `pubnub-ruby.rb` in the [repo for that gem](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/ruby/lib). Try running `$ bundle install` or `$ gem update pubnub-ruby`.

Comment: gem update pubnub-ruby
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update  -- it seems to think it's up to date. it's very strange, pubnub-ruby.rb merely contains: require "./pubnub.rb" if I change that to require "pubnub.rb" - it passes that error but gets stuck on pubnub.rb:24:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./lib/PubnubCrypto.rb (LoadError)
 ... and yes pubnubCrypto is not to be found

Comment: From looking at the history of that repo it looks like they did some name changes. Perhaps try uninstalling and reinstalling the gem with `$ gem uninstall pubnub-ruby` and then `$ gem install pubnub-ruby`

Comment: Resolved - you pointed me in the right direction. It seems pubnub-ruby stopped at 0.0.9 , switched to 'pubnub' gem and installed 0.1.9 and the error is cleared. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that the new PubNub Ruby Gem is called "pubnub" and use one of the following to install "pubnub" ruby:

    `sudo gem install pubnub`

or

    `sudo gem1.9 install pubnub`

http://rubygems.org/gems/pubnub